# select and hide an element that is added after an HTML email

Tags: html, css, quoted-printable

I am using acuityscheduling and i created a custom HTML email that is sent to my clients.
Acuityscheduling adds after each Email automatically the following tag:

```
<p style="font-size:80%;color:#666;margin-top:50px;">
    <a href="http://email.acuityscheduling.com/mpss/c/-gA/e9k/t.28z/6aBhdLdPQ6KxpNGaeD4rog/h8/UJxRWqLdMny-2BJZ6UuVMMWnqzFS9vlR8umKlzm-2BD48FWClzqAQ2sUKTfxaGr-2B4NVNtGbbfx6xRx8CVJSodw-2Ba1hjQmeVJLGl66LRd4sO6Z3qvzDpU3IgUaim3ezFesuYk">Unsubscribe</a>
</p>
```

The link is variable..
How can I hide this?
**The HTML does not allow me to use js and a style tag..**
Can I select an element outside of my custom HTML and hide it with CSS?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try adding `"display:none"`

```
<p style="font-size:80%;color:#666;margin-top:50px;display:none;">
    <a href="http://email.acuityscheduling.com/mpss/c/-gA/e9k/t.28z/6aBhdLdPQ6KxpNGaeD4rog/h8/UJxRWqLdMny-2BJZ6UuVMMWnqzFS9vlR8umKlzm-2BD48FWClzqAQ2sUKTfxaGr-2B4NVNtGbbfx6xRx8CVJSodw-2Ba1hjQmeVJLGl66LRd4sO6Z3qvzDpU3IgUaim3ezFesuYk">Unsubscribe</a>
</p>
```

Comment: u cant add style to anchor tag too ?